# what is site policy about formatting?

Tags: discussion

I get jumped on all the time, but usually those more adept at HTML re-format my posts.

Are poor HTML skills a reason to stop people from posting?  Just how many ways are people going to think of to interfere with free expression?

Comment: It's actually very easy.. why don't u learn how to do it? when i was new i also did ask others about how to do that yellow quote.. many new users can't do it properly and others help them.. so it is not an issue..

Comment: Formatting is strongly encouraged since it aids the H.SE reader to understand the flow of one's argument clearly. If your aim is to "put something out there" then formatting will seem vestigial. On the other hand, if your claim is that you are only interested from a learning and experiential point of view, this question would have not sprung into existence. Giving the benefit of the doubt, again, I'm sure you will find that learning formatting will give your content clearer reach on the site.

Answer (score 9):

All Stack Exchange sites use [Markdown](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format. It is simple and easy to learn. No expert skills are required to format the posts in Markdown.

Asking to post in a proper way is not a way to interfere or being rude. If you are offended  by normal help center articles which are always shown to newbies, I can say nothing. Why don't you try posting in a proper format instead of blaming someone that they are interfering in free expression? Let me tell you that Stack Exchange doesn't give you the right of free expression. It has rules on how to post questions and how to behave with others, how to address people in the posts.

Just click on the question mark on the right corner while you are posting a question or answer.

[image: Help for formatting]

Every time you ask a question, system shows you how to format your question.

[image: Picture showing information how to format your question]

We want questions and answers to be clear and easy to read. There is no hurry in posting questions quickly. It is your post. So, you have the responsibility of the poster to provide the post with proper formatting.  Leaving to the editors or other people on the site to format is ..... well, not always encouraged. Users may help in few cases but each and every post? No. It is not encouraged. Readers have to search what is a quote, what is a link, what are your own words if the posts are not formatted properly.

Check the difference between the readability of the posts before and after formatting.

#### [Before formatting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/11453/1)

#### [After formatting](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/11453/2)

You can notice that there is a lot of difference.

I know that many new users have problem with this formatting but they eventually learn when they see experienced users' edits or reading properly formatted posts or by going through the [help center link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) which existing users have posted in comments. Just go through the help center link, there won't be the any further problems. The time taken by the editors in salvaging your posts can be used for something else if you yourself post in a proper way.

When you want interaction from other people on the site, take some time to listen what they say. They only do that to help you not to target you. Please go through the helpful links users redirect you to. No need to take it as offensive or personal. [Offensive has a different meaning](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).