# Showing relevant formatting option

Tags: feature-request

While writing a post, Hinduism SE site shows "How to Format" option on the right side.

Like below:

[image]

However the part in the circle looks irrelevant for this site. Can we remove this and put some other formatting option which can look more relevant for the site ?

Comment: I think this is actually added recently. Previously it was normal. See the screenshot in [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1243/5212)

Comment: @Sarva It can be possible that it came after new material theme design

Comment: Dupe on Meta SE: [“How to format” block mentions syntax highlighting even if it is not available on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326375)